# How to merge dependent globals from multiple calls to exec with independent globals dicts

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-exec

This code works fine - it defines `do_return` as a global, it defines `do_proxy` as a global, and `do_proxy` can resolve `do_return` when called.

```py
g1 = {}
exec("def do_return(): return 1", g1)
exec("def do_proxy(): return do_return()", g1)
merged = {**g1}
merged.pop("__builtins__")
print(merged.keys())
exec("print(do_proxy())", merged)
```

```
$ python3 main.py 
dict_keys(['do_return', 'do_proxy'])
1
```

This code doesn't:

```py
g1 = {}
g2 = {}
exec("def do_return(): return 1", g1)
exec("def do_proxy(): return do_return()", g2)
merged = {**g1, **g2}
merged.pop("__builtins__")
print(merged.keys())
exec("print(do_proxy())", merged)
```

It complaints that `do_return` is not defined, even though there is a global named `do_return`:

```
$ python3 main.py 
dict_keys(['do_return', 'do_proxy'])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 8, in <module>
    exec("print(do_proxy())", merged)
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 1, in do_proxy
NameError: name 'do_return' is not defined
```

Is there a way to merge dependent globals from multiple calls to `exec` which didn't share the same globals dict when they were originally called?

The same happens if I call `global do_return` inside `do_proxy` (though if that was required, I would also expect the first example to fail, similarly requiring it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call a function, it uses its own reference to the global namespace where it was defined, rather than the globals of where it is being called from. You can see this by checking the `__globals__` attribute of a function. In the first version of your code, `merged['do_proxy'].__globals__` is a reference to `g1`, which also contains your `do_return` function. But in the second version of your code, `do_proxy`'s `__globals__` is a reference to `g2`, which does not contain the other function.

This makes sense if you think about it. It's similar to how a function defined in another module will look for names in its module's global namespace, not in the namespace where you've imported it, and functions in two different modules can only interact if you pass references around after importing them, or if one of the modules imports the other.

There might be some workarounds you could use in your code. One option would be to merge the `g1` definitions into the `g2` dictionary, rather than creating a new dict with the combined results.

```
g2.update(g1) # instead of creating merged
```

Of course, this works for `do_proxy` referring to `do_return`, but it wouldn't work in reverse, if `do_return` wanted to call `do_proxy` (perhaps as part of some kind of recursive algorithm). You could perhaps merge both ways, but that would probably get messy.

Comment: The biggest problem with an `update`-based option is that the dicts can diverge again, particularly if any functions use `global` or if any more code is `exec`uted in either dict.